# Fine Uploader retrying after successful upload

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I'm using fine uploader and it was working pretty well. Now, it retries even though it successfully uploaded. So then, I have four files instead of just one.

http://fineuploader.com/

My code:

```
<!-- The element where Fine Uploader will exist. -->
<div id="qq-drop-zone">
    <div id="fine-uploader"></div>
    <span class="dragndrop">Drag and Drop</span>
</div>

<!-- Fine Uploader -->
<script src="/modules/fine-uploader/fine-uploader.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/template" id="qq-template">
    <div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader" qq-drop-area-text="Drop files here">
        <div class="qq-total-progress-bar-container-selector qq-total-progress-bar-container">
            <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-total-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar qq-total-progress-bar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="qq-upload-drop-area-selector qq-upload-drop-area" qq-hide-dropzone>
            <span class="qq-upload-drop-area-text-selector"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="button qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button">
            <div>Upload From Your</div>
        </div>
        <span class="qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing">
            <span>Processing dropped files...</span>
            <span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span>
        </span>
        <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals">
            <li class="clearfix">
                <img class="qq-thumbnail-selector" qq-max-size="100" qq-server-scale>
                <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector">
                    <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar"></div>
                </div>
                <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
                <div class="form">
                    <div class="input_block caption">
                        <label for="caption">Caption</label>
                        <input type="text" class="caption_input" data-key="title" placeholder="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="input_block qq-hide">
                        <span class="qq-edit-filename-icon-selector qq-edit-filename-icon" aria-label="Edit filename"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="file_data">
                    <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
                    <input class="qq-edit-filename-selector qq-edit-filename" tabindex="0" type="text">
                    <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="ghost button qq-btn qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="ghost button qq-btn qq-upload-retry-selector qq-upload-retry">Retry</button>
                <button type="button" class="button qq-btn qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete">Delete</button>
                <span role="status" class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <dialog class="qq-alert-dialog-selector">
            <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
            <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="button qq-cancel-button-selector">Close</button>
            </div>
        </dialog>

        <dialog class="qq-confirm-dialog-selector">
            <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
            <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="ghost button qq-cancel-button-selector">No</button>
                <button type="button" class="button qq-ok-button-selector">Yes</button>
            </div>
        </dialog>

        <dialog class="qq-prompt-dialog-selector">
            <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
            <input type="text">
            <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="ghost button qq-cancel-button-selector">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="button qq-ok-button-selector">Ok</button>
            </div>
        </dialog>
    </div>
</script>

<script>
    var dragAndDropModule = new qq.DragAndDrop({
        dropZoneElements: [document.getElementById('qq-drop-zone')],
        classes: {
          dropActive: "dragover"
        },
        callbacks: {
              processingDroppedFiles: function() {},
              processingDroppedFilesComplete: function(files, dropTarget) {
                fineUploaderBasicInstance.addFiles(files); //this submits the dropped files to Fine Uploader
              }
         }
    }), 
    fineUploaderBasicInstance = new qq.FineUploader({
        debug: true,
        element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader'),
        request: {
            endpoint: '/ajax/fine-uploader.php'
        },
        retry: {
            enableAuto: true
        }
    });
</script>
```

hopefully that helps

Comment: It is not possible to help unless you provide your code and browser console messages. There is no such known issue with Fine Uploader, so it is a matter of determining where the error is in your code/environment.

Comment: @RayNicholus added my code. There's not much to it. I just don't even know where to start debugging this thing. I've just hit a bunch of dead ends.

Comment: Like I mentioned, I'll need browser console logs as well.

Comment: Thank you! While I was grabbing the browser console logs, I noticed that there was extra text in the XHR responseText which made the JSON invalid. Without a valid response, it registered as a failed upload and kicked off a retry. I got rid of the extra text and it works again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was extra text in the XHR responseText which made the JSON invalid. Without a valid response, it registered as a failed upload and kicked off a retry. I got rid of the extra text and it works again.